# Dynamic Query in Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

I am implementing a search screen and  I have some optional parameter coming up. In oracle I used to give true or 1=1 condition for optional parameter which is not supported in Spanner.
How we can achieve the same in Spanner SQL?

```
Sample Query 
select mark.* from  
abc mark join xyz mchhier on  mark.X=mchhier.X where 
--Mandatory
mark.X=123 and 
--Below Params are Optional
mchhier.G in (null) and mchhier.C (null) and mchhier.D in (null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Spanner also supports conditions like `WHERE True` and `WHERE 1=1`, so it should be possible to use the same strategy as in Oracle.

The following is for example a valid Spanner query:

```sql
select mark.*
from abc mark
join xyz mchhier on mark.X=mchhier.X
where 
--Mandatory
mark.X=123
--@SomeParam could be NULL
AND CASE
  -- If param is null, the condition will always be true
  WHEN @SomeParam IS NULL THEN TRUE
  ELSE mchhier.G in (@SomeParam)
END
```

Comment: When I try to give true or 1=1 in in clause I am getting "No matching signature for operator IN for argument types INT64 and {BOOL} at line 15, column 21"